# Issues with ng-bind-html in an INPUT

Tags: angularjs

I want to parse the following strings in an Input:

<>, <, >, = (without comma)

The Input will be binded by this Snippet:

**JS**

```
$scope.json = null;
$scope.filter = JSON.parse(data);
$scope.$watch('filter', function (newValue) {
    $scope.json = JSON.stringify(newValue, null, 2);
    $scope.output = computed(newValue.group);
}, true);
```

If I now use:

```
<input type="text" ng-bind="output"/>
```

I get the output: `&lt;&gt;` (for eg for <>)

If I use

```
<input type="text" ng-bind-html="output"/>
```

Nothing happens.

Correct would be the <> in the input

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this filter to parse your operators.

```
filter("decode",function(){
    return function(str){ 

      var el = document.createElement("div");
      el.innerHTML = str;
      str =  el.innerText || el.textContent;
      return str;

    }
})
```

Html

```
 <input type="text" ng-bind="model|decode"  />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I´ve added the filter and set the ng-bind to ng-bind="output | decode" but nothing happens, no exception...

Comment: if you are intend of one way binding then go with ng-bind.otherwise, you can replace ng-model instead of ng-bind

Comment: With ng-model, still nothing happens. For a better understanding: I use this plugin http://mfauveau.github.io/angular-query-builder/ and want to parse the "Example Output". Thank you four your help, I´m doing my first steps with angularJS :-)

Comment: I´ve made a Plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/lk0qfa0mjEZZd5W0QFKJ?p=preview    If I insert your Filter, nothing happens. If you press "Add Condition" you can select an operator.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) binding to automatically parse these characters.

```
<input ng-model="text">
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xvzj3u2p/1/)